# C# Check two labels, and make a action

Tags: c#

I've got my account and account password two TextBox'es, and im trying to make a timer, which check if the textbox and textbox2 matches, like we could say like, i got 1 textbox which is account, and textbox2, which is password. How could i make that when in the textbox user writes a username which is in my string, and in the textbox2 password, which is from that username, the textbox icon will change?
Its my script of changing the icon, but the bug is when you write other user name and other password, the icon does change.
The first one is for password, the second is for usernames.

```
 if (new string[] { "dziugas", "root", "doxas" }.Contains(metroTextBox1.Text))
        {
            Image img = Properties.Resources.Good_Pincode_48px; // Right'as
            metroTextBox1.Icon = img;
            //////////////////////////////

        }
        else
        {
            // new wrong().Show();
            Image img = Properties.Resources.Wrong_Pincode_48px; // Wrong'as
            metroTextBox1.Icon = img;

        }


 //Tikrina user names;
        if (new string[] { "flairskull", "admin", "domaslox" }.Contains(metroTextBox2.Text))
        {
            Image img = Properties.Resources.Ok_48px; // Right'as
            metroTextBox2.Icon = img;
            //////////////////////////////

        }
        else
        {
            // new wrong().Show();
            Image img = Properties.Resources.Cancel_48px; // Wrong'as
            metroTextBox2.Icon = img;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you using windows forms?

Comment: Yes emsimpson92

Comment: Try calling refresh() after you change the icon. That should solve your problem.

Comment: Nope, i just don't know how to make a script which will work when the string username and password will match

Comment: I see. I didn't quite understand the question. Just set up an event handler for the textbox when the text changes [see here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/textbox) Then check to see if they match and you should achieve your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I've got my script done:

```
if (usernames.Contains(metroTextBox2.Text) && passwords.Contains(metroTextBox1.Text) && Array.IndexOf(usernames, metroTextBox2.Text) == Array.IndexOf(passwords, metroTextBox1.Text))
        {
            Image img = Properties.Resources.Ok_48px; // Right'as
            metroTextBox2.Icon = img;
            // Kitas image
            metroTextBox1.Icon = Properties.Resources.Ok_48px;
        }
        else
        {
            // new wrong().Show();
            Image img = Properties.Resources.Cancel_48px; // Wrong'as
            metroTextBox2.Icon = img;
            //Kitas image
            metroTextBox1.Icon = Properties.Resources.Cancel_48px;
        }
```